# Use selection as condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to use the `selection as` column as condition?
Let's say I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE stuffs (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
last_location VARCHAR(50),
user_id int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT users.id,
  CASE stuffs.status(
    WHEN NULL THEN 'DO NOT HAVE STUFF'
    WHEN 'NOT IN POSSESSION' AND stuffs.last_location IS NULL THEN 'NEVER HAD THE STUFF'
    WHEN 'NOT IN POSSESSION' AND stuffs.last_location IS NOT NULL THEN 'LOST'
    ELSE 'IN POSSESSION'
  ) as stuff_status
FROM users
LEFT JOIN stuffs ON stuffs.user_id = users.id;
```

My question is can I add

```
WHERE stuff_status = 'LOST'
```

in the query? Or Do I have to rewrite the whole subquery into where condition for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most databases, you would either have to repeat the entire `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause, or subquery your current query and then restrict in a `WHERE` clause outside the subquery.  However, MySQL has overloaded its `HAVING` operator to allow using aliases.  So, you may try this version:

```sql
SELECT u.id,
  CASE WHEN s.status IS NULL
       THEN 'DO NOT HAVE STUFF'
       WHEN s.status = 'NOT IN POSSESSION' AND s.last_location IS NULL
       THEN 'NEVER HAD THE STUFF'
       WHEN s.status = 'NOT IN POSSESSION' AND s.last_location IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'LOST'
       ELSE 'IN POSSESSION' END AS stuff_status
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN s ON s.user_id = u.id
HAVING stuff_status = 'LOST';
```

But note that since you are just checking for the `LOST` case, you could also just repeat its logic in a regular `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT u.id,
  CASE WHEN s.status IS NULL
       THEN 'DO NOT HAVE STUFF'
       WHEN s.status = 'NOT IN POSSESSION' AND s.last_location IS NULL
       THEN 'NEVER HAD THE STUFF'
       WHEN s.status = 'NOT IN POSSESSION' AND s.last_location IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'LOST'
       ELSE 'IN POSSESSION' END AS stuff_status
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN s ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE s.status = 'NOT IN POSSESSION' AND s.last_location IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: the logic is just stub that I came up with on the fly, the actual query I'm having to do has a very long subquery, which is why I want to ask if there's a way to avoid having to write a long query

Comment: @NganCun ... and I have answered your question.  Either refer to the `CASE` alias in a `HAVING` clause, or simply repeat the correct logic in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want in the results only the rows where the `CASE` expression returns `'LOST'` you don't need that `CASE` expression.
Just pick the condition that returns `'LOST'` and place it in the `WHERE` clause.

Also, you should use an `INNER` join instead of  `LEFT` join, because the condition `status = 'NOT IN POSSESSION' AND last_location IS NOT NULL` means that you want in the results only the matching rows:

```
SELECT u.id, 'LOST' AS stuff_status
FROM users u INNER JOIN stuffs s
ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE s.status = 'NOT IN POSSESSION' AND s.last_location IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The point of the question was to ask if I can use the selection as a condition, the logic is just stub I came up with on the fly, sorry if it's confusing

Comment: @NganCun my answer is based on the code in your question. If your requirement is different then you should ask a new question.